# Is there any kind of syntax error in this code?

Tags: excel, vba

My aim is to copy some data from one worksheet (Sheet 1) and paste (only values) it to other worksheet (Missing Num - Selected Part). I have written the code but it is showing the error - "Subscript out of Range". May be I am making any syntax error or may be I am missing some function of VBA. Please help me.

I have written the code. It is shown below.

```
Sub Check_123()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, i_max As Integer, j_max As Integer
i = 0
j = 0
i_max = 10 'Max value of i that can be entered
j_max = 31 'Range of columns - 6 Num to 36 Num
For i = 1 To i_max Step 1
    Worksheets("Missing Num - Selected Part").Range("C5").Value = Worksheets("Missing Num - Selected Part").Cells(i + 3, 5).Value   
        For j = 1 To j_max Step 1
            Worksheets("Missing Num - Selected Part").Cells(3 + i, 5 + j).Value = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(38, 3 + j).Value
            'RHS is original strip from which data has to be extracted & LHS where data has to be entered
        Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel cell indexes start with `1`, not `0`, for both rows and columns. For example, cell `C2` is accessed with `Cells(2,3)`. So make sure your `i` and `j` have initial value of `1`.